# Swift: Include Element in UINavigationItem and change its height

Tags: swift, interface, uikit, uinavigationbar

I am trying to include a segmented control in the top-bar or navigation item, like in the App Store. How can this be done?

[image]

I tried to add a toolbar below the navigation item, however there is a line between these two elements...

Comment: You should look at the sample code provided by apple [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/samplecode/NavBar/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007418).

Comment: You can design a fake view with the exact background color as the navigation bar, and add the segmented control there

Comment: @Xcoder123, does this mean subclassing? If so, what superclass? (BTW, I agree, this isn't very trivial. Just wondering if I was on the same page as you.)

Comment: @dfd I don't know what superclass you are talking about... Just a view with grey background color, that's what i meant

Comment: @Xcoder123, maybe I mistook you. The OP is asking to use a *UINavigationBar* (maybe a controller also) and add a *UISegmentedControl* to it "seamlessly (no dividers). I, uh.... just realized what you are suggesting! Nice. That's a much better answer than what I was thinking. You should write up something as an answer.

Comment: Maybe, I'll se if it's worth it. I'm afraid that the OP is not looking for that, but I'll consider it